# how to use c/c++ module with nginx

Tags: c, macos, nginx

I'm trying to build a web server with [nginx](http://nginx.org/).

My PC is a Mac OS so I just `brew install nginx`. It works well. I can execute `nginx` which is located at `/usr/local/bin/` to start the server. Also, when I visit `http://localhost`, I can get the main page, which is located at `/usr/local/var/www/index.html`.

However, I can't find any source code of nginx.

So I download its source code from [here](http://nginx.org/download/).

Now I'm confused. I don't know how to organize my project.

For example, for this [hello world](https://github.com/perusio/nginx-hello-world-module/blob/master/ngx_http_hello_world_module.c), it just need `#include <ngx_config.h> #include <ngx_core.h> #include <ngx_http.h>`. It seems that it could use the source code of nginx as a c standard library.

How can I do the same thing?
Where should I put my developed module?

Comment: C or C++? Or C and C++ separately. There is no such language as C/C++

Comment: http://www.evanmiller.org/nginx-modules-guide.html

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya  For now I'm not sure if it works for C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two seems like very good starting point to me:

http://www.evanmiller.org/nginx-modules-guide.html
http://nutrun.com/weblog/2009/08/15/hello-world-nginx-module.html

I haven't made any modules myself, but when I searched for one of my own problem solution I found the above links and these looks promising to me.

I will update you any progress I made during my experiment. And if you have already made any progress, please do share.